# Is there a way to link to same page area in Shopify?

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor, shopify

Normally it works, using this example. http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000049.htm

But I am trying to do this in Shopify and so far no luck.  I have a dropdown menu with headings that link to specific parts of a page. In the Shopify Nav links, I am using a "web address" option to add a link that looks like this. http://mysite.myshopify.com/pages/vollyball#anchor.

It links to that page but it does not slide down to the the specific area of the page that it's suppose to.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in link,

```
<a href="#title4">Title 4</a>
```

This is for specific area of page.

```
<a name="title4">Title 4</a>
```

Comment: Ahh yes, the reason mine wasn't working was because I had it like this. <a name="#title4">Title 4</a>. I removed the # and now it works.  Thanks.